# Is entropy being maximized and the norm being minimized by the same (unique) probability vector somehow related?

Tags: linear-algebra, entropy, quantum-information

Consider the set of probability vectors
$$
\mathcal P_n=\Big\lbrace x\in[0,1]^n\,\Big|\,\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1\Big\rbrace\subset\mathbb C^n
$$
for any $n\in\mathbb N$ where $x_i$ is the $i$-th component of $x$. Since $\mathcal P_n$ is a non-empty convex and closed set, [there exists a unique vector of minimal norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_projection_theorem) which, unsurprisingly, turns out to be the equilibrium $\frac1n(1,\ldots,1)$ as a simple consequence of Cauchy-Schwarz.

On the other hand given $x\in \mathcal P_n$ we can define the entropy as in quantum information via

$$
S:\mathcal P_n\to\mathbb R_0^+\qquad x\mapsto-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\log(x_i).
$$

It is well known that the entropy is maximal if and only if $x=\frac1n(1,\ldots,1)$.

> **Question:** I wondered if the entropy being maximized and the norm being minimized by the same unique vector $\frac1n(1,\ldots,1)$ is somehow related? I don't see a direct connection since the logarithm obviously is not linear but I still feel like there might be some kind of link between those two results.

Thanks in advance for any answer or comment!

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118169/is-there-a-relationship-between-entropy-of-a-fininte-distrete-probability-distri

Comment: Another viewpoint on this is related to schur-convex and schur-concave functions from the majorization theory. Essentially norm is a schur-convex and entropy is a schur-concave function. In most scenarios, the solution to minimizing ( maximizing) a schur-convex function (concave function) is the symmetrical solution where every co-ordinate is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed today that this old question of mine is on top of the list of unanswered quantum-information questions (despite not being an open question anymore). While both comments to this question offer valuable insight, the [cited MO page](https://mathoverflow.net/a/118373/) provides a deep link between entropy and 2-norm which -- looking back -- I found most satisfying.